# can't IP restriction on PHP files with HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, ip-restrictions

I have a directory and Protected with htaccess for IP Restriction.
IP restriction work good but just for Directory's Except `.php` files.

***example :***

```
site.com/dir/             <-- Get Access Denied Error
site.com/dir/index.php    <-- Open page without access denied error
```

***My .htaccess files:***

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound2.html
ErrorDocument 403 /notfound2.html
    AuthName "Access Restrict"
    AuthType Basic 
<Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 47.147.50.5
</Limit>
```

I want to restrict a directory (with all objects includes php files too) to access from just a IP
Where's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to deny Directory Listing.

Try `Option -Indexes` or `IndexIgnore *.tgz *.sql *.tar` for specific files.

see http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings for more info.

Comment: Thanks Rufinus , but I want to restrict a directory (with all objects includes php files too) to access from just a IP .

Comment: this you have already handled by your limit block. (the auth lines are useless in this case)